# Count data with mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i have this following table

```
id   kelurahan    status
1    Pegambiran   Netral
2    Pegambiran   Netral
3    Kejaksan     Positif
4    Kesenden     Positif
5    Pegambiran   Negatif
```

i want to get result like this

```
kelurahan    count_positif   count_netral   count_negatif   total
Pegambiran   0               2              1               3
Kejaksan     1               0              0               1
Kesenden     1               0              0               1
```

i tried this query

```
SELECT kelurahan, 
(SELECT COUNT(status) FROM tbl_monitoring WHERE status = 'Positif' GROUP BY kelurahan LIMIT 1) AS count_positif, 
(SELECT COUNT(status) FROM tbl_monitoring WHERE status = 'Netral' GROUP BY kelurahan) AS count_netral,
(SELECT COUNT(status) FROM tbl_monitoring WHERE status = 'Negatif' GROUP BY kelurahan) AS count_negatif, 
COUNT(kelurahan) AS total 
FROM tbl_monitoring GROUP BY kelurahan
```

i get the result like this

[image]

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Rather than running the `count_[COLUMN]` as subqueries on the `SELECT` (e.g, avoid `(SELECT COUNT(status) ...)`), you can use the combination of `SUM` and `CASE` from the table itself to perform the aggregate - e.g, `SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Positif' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should use SUM, not COUNT.
2. Tested on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccce13f8088c640fc75271c0d87633f1)

```
SELECT 
  kelurahan, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Positif' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_positif,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Netral' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_netral,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Negatif' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_negatif,
  SUM(1) AS total
FROM tbl_monitoring
GROUP BY kelurahan;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's work like a charm. and i want to ask, what is SUM(1) mean?

Comment: sum(1) is equivalent to count(*) which returns the count of all rows for the group (kelurahan).